# Wordpress previous post shortlink

Tags: wordpress

Hey guys so far I have this code that gives me the full link to my previous post

```
<?php $prevPost = get_previous_post(FALSE);
if($prevPost) {?>
<div class="prev1" onclick="javascript:_gaq.push(['_trackSocial', 'Nav', 'Prev-Thumb']);">
<?php previous_post_link('%link',"«", FALSE); ?>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

But I want the shortlink instead of the full link

How can I accomplish that ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swap out your existing code with the following.

```
<?php
// Get the previous post.
$previous_post = get_previous_post();

// Check a post was found.
if ( $previous_post ) : ?>
    <div class="prev1" onclick="javascript:_gaq.push(['_trackSocial', 'Nav', 'Prev-Thumb']);">
        <a href="<?php echo wp_get_shortlink( $previous_post->ID ); ?>" title="Permalink to previous post">&laquo;</a>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Pleased I could help :)

Comment: you might help me with this one too
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21516030/position-element-fixed-beside-image

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer if it worked for you. I'll take a look at your other question by the way