# position element fixed beside image

Tags: css, position, fixed

Hey guys it a bit hard for me to explain, but I'll try as best I can.
I have a sharing div on my side

```
<div class="share">
```

And I want to fixe it in the center of the screen top:50% on left of the image.
I tried many css thing but no success.

here's the webpage
http://giantgag.com/?p=10272

It doesn't work with all screen resolution. The sharing buttons goes over the image

Comment: where is the webpage or fiddle?

Comment: where is the webpage?

Comment: sorry http://giantgag.com/?p=10272

Answer (score 0):

Actually the css is working fine. `top:50%` keeps the top point of div at 50% distance from top which is what you are seeing in your site. 
For correct solution irrespective of any screen size, use javascript to give the position to div at onload.

Comment: The top is good, it is the left right that I can't accomplish

Comment: what you actually want to do and where you want to put your share div?

Comment: on the left side of the image but if the screen resolution is smaller or image s bigger the buttons goes over the image. The max image width is 728px. I'll try with @media or something like that